# How to write time range condition for datetime field?

Tags: datetime, 9

I need a query that will show events only in specific time range. For an example:

1. Event 1 -> 2022-06-12T20:00:00
2. Event 2 -> 2022-06-11T11:00:00
3. Event 3 -> 2022-04-12T09:00:00
4. Event 4 -> 2022-05-10T10:00:00

when I set the time range from 9 am to 11:30 am it should show Event 2, Event 3, and Event 4.

The field that I am querying is the DateTime range type.

Is there any way to write a query using drupal 9 dynamic queries?
Thank you.